# How do I use Ruby 1.9 with Managed C++?

Tags: ruby, managed-c++, static-linking

I'm trying to create a dot net library to use ruby, for the sake of this, I'm linking
ruby's static library but I'm getting some LNK error.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for, but have you checked out [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/)? It allows you to call .NET libraries from a Ruby script.

Comment: I know IronRuby and Ruby .NET, I just want to create something different, I just want to wrap ruby for using it in .net